# Date and time with numbers in python?

Tags: python, date, time

I need to get the current date with numbers, like that: `14:45:35:233 08.05.2016`. I didn't find a function for that in the time module, is there any short way to do that?

Comment: @heemayl `233` are the milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want  parse from specific date time format to another one. Maybe it'd be what you looking for, take a  look:

```
>>> import datetime

>>> strdate = '14:45:35:233 08.05.2016'
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(strdate, '%H:%M:%S:233 %d.%m.%Y')
>>> dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2016-05-08'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) and get whatever [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use strftime to format time.

`datetime.datetime.now()` will give current time.

To get the time in "Hours:Minutes:Seconds:Microseconds Date.Month.Year " Format use `strftime("%H:%M:%S:%f %d.%m.%Y")`

```
import datetime
a=datetime.datetime.now()
a.strftime("%H:%M:%S:%f %d.%m.%Y")
```

## Output

'16:50:54:238874 08.05.2016'

Comment: It's better not just to dump code but to provide an explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import time
>>> ts = time.time()
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%H.%M.%S %d.%m.%Y')
```

Output :

```
'18.20.06 08.05.2016'
```